# Where to find open tabular hyperspectral data for machine learning research?

Tags: machine-learning, agriculture

Where can i find open datasets regarding " Wheat/Maize Leaf Spectra with Associated water content, Potassium and Nitrogen Measurements" for machine learning research i.e. hyperspectral tabular data collected from a field spectroradiometer along with chemical parameters.